# How can I display file info of a man?

Tags: command-line, man, info

I know when you are in a man page it will display the file name at the bottom  inside the man.

How can I do the same thing manually?

Comment: I still can't figure it out. I mean, when you scroll down to the end of a man page, where the (END) prompt appears, is there a way to display the number of lines in the man?

Comment: Yes, I verified that behavior before I posted my answer. With the environment variables set as I've said, then pressing "G" to get to the bottom of the man page, you get the line count. Try `$ MANPAGER=less LESS=-M man ls` I just tried that here, and verified that it gives the line count.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure it is possible to do everything you ask, because `man(1)` sends the formatted man page data to your pager program via a pipe. This would prevent showing a file name, for one thing.

You can get a line count at least like so:

1. Set your `MANPAGER` or `PAGER` environment variable to `less`.
2. Add `-M` to your `LESS` environment variable, to get the "long prompt", which includes the line count.

Instead of `-M`, you can build your own `less` prompt with the `-P` option to get even more details. Again, though, there are some things in what you ask that `less` simply won't have access to when acting as `man`'s pager program.